# Convert array to comma separated strings

Tags: javascript, dom

`add` method of the `classList` accepts strings only and not an array (`String [, String [, ...]]`) so I wonder if there's an elegant way to convert an array to a list of strings without the obvious looping:

```
var breakpoints = {
    "extraSmall"    : [ "only screen and (max-width: 575px)" ],
    "small"         : [ "only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px)" ],
    "medium"        : [ "only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)" ],
    "large"         : [ "only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)" ],
    "extraLarge"    : [ "only screen and (min-width: 1200px)" ],
}
Object.keys(breakpoints).map(feature => document.documentElement.classList.add(feature));
```

Basically, I'm looking to add multiple classes in one call.

Comment: Don't use `.map` for simple looping.

Comment: @VLAZ `.map` is 70% faster than `forEach`

Comment: Yes, there is. [`someArray.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) joins elements into a comma-separated string. Just you have no array to join.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I get the question. `.add()` doesn't accept an array, so you want to turn it to...a list of strings? In most cases "list" and "array" are synonymous in JS, so I'm not getting the rationale. It seems like you just need use spread syntax or `.apply` to pass an array as the arguments to the method but the question doesn't really ask for that.

Comment: You can do `document.documentElement.classList.add.apply(document.documentElement.classList, Object.keys(breakpoints))`, but this is worse than your loop.

Comment: @georg Why would you think its worse than a loop?

Comment: @3zzy: well it looks horrible, doesn't it? Unless you already have a separate variable for `document.documentElement.classList` or can wrap it into a function like `addClasses(elem, array)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `add` method accepts multiple classes as parameters you could use spread syntax `...` on object keys to pass each element from keys as a class.

```js
var breakpoints = { "extraSmall"    : [ "only screen and (max-width: 575px)" ], "small"         : [ "only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px)" ], "medium"        : [ "only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)" ], "large"         : [ "only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)" ], "extraLarge"    : [ "only screen and (min-width: 1200px)" ],}
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const classes = Object.keys(breakpoints);
div.classList.add(...classes);
```

```html
<div>Div</div>
```

For older version of browsers that do not support spread syntax you can use `apply` method.

```js
var breakpoints = { "extraSmall"    : [ "only screen and (max-width: 575px)" ], "small"         : [ "only screen and (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px)" ], "medium"        : [ "only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)" ], "large"         : [ "only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)" ], "extraLarge"    : [ "only screen and (min-width: 1200px)" ],}
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const classes = Object.keys(breakpoints);
div.classList.add.apply(div.classList, classes)
```

```html
<div>Div</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, and probably worth keeping here for someone else but I can't use spread in my app (damn IE and no babel).

Comment: @3zzy so, why not just use `.apply()`? It's what Babel will transpile spread syntax to, anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ Babel would transpile to `call` ;) but yea, I'll use `apply`, just mentioned about the compatibility so @Nenad can update his answer before I accept.

Comment: @3zzy [Why would Babel transpile to `.call`?](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgIYBpEBG-E-AJvivsPgOb4AW-MAlIgN4C-AUKhpgHSCA2gEZ8AJnwBmfABYAusy5A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.6.4&externalPlugins=) Spread syntax has always been syntax sugar for `.apply` in functions.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to create a new array, don't use `.map`. Rather, you want to perform side-effects, so you should use `forEach` or a `for` loop instead:

```
for (const newClass of Object.keys(breakpoints)) {
  document.documentElement.classList.add(newClass)
}
```

To avoid looping entirely, you could (inelegantly) concatenate with the existing `className`:

```
document.documentElement.className += ` ${Object.keys(breakpoints).join(' ')}`;
```

If the `<html>` tag doesn't already have a class name, the leading space is unnecessary. If it's uncertain in advance whether it'll have a class name or not, it'd be easier to use `classList.add` instead.